# Matlab intellisense for objects user defined classes in Script files

Tags: matlab, intellisense

I would like to know that is there a way for intellisense to work for user defined classes. If I create object of user defined class in command window that I can see the properties and method of that class by pressing the tab button in front of `"Object + ."`. However, if I create object in a script file or function then intellisense does not work. Do I need to enable some functionality or Matlab does not have this capability. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just tested on MATLAB R2012a, and intellisense works as expected on a user-defined class, with the following settings in "File" > "Preferences..." > "Keyboard" for "Tab completion" section:

```
[v] Enable in Command Window
[v] Enable in Editor/Debugger
[ ] Tab key narrows completions
```

However, because not always the type of a variable can be determined from the code, this might fail from time to time.